# having trouble getting my bot to join voice channel and play music

Tags: javascript, discord.js, audio-player, ytdl

error i get is `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'join')`

code:

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');

 
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
    async execute(message, args) {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voicechannel;
        
        
 
        
        if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
 
        const validURL = (str) =>{
            var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
            if(!regex.test(str)){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
 
        if(validURL(args[0])){
 
            const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            const stream  = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});
 
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
                message.channel.send('leaving channel');
            });
 
            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}!***`)
 
            return
        }
 
        
        const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
 
        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
 
            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
 
        }
 
        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
 
        if(video){
            const stream  = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
            });
 
            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send('No video results found');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.join()` does not work anymore in discord.js v13.
You need to define the connection like this:

```js
const { joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');

const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
    channelId: channel.id,
    guildId: channel.guild.id,
    adapterCreator: channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
});
```

You can find more information [here](https://discordjs.guide/voice/voice-connections.html)